# How Can I Use Flickr API to return images from a place

Tags: php, api

I am using justifiedimage gallery, swipebox anda PHP Flickr API Wrapper to return and display images in a gallery.

The trouble is, currently it displays the images obtained from a certain user account.
Is there a way to modify the below code, so that it only displays images from "Southampton" as opposed to displaying images from a specified userID?

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="justifiedGallery/justifiedGallery.min.css" />
    <script src="justifiedGallery/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="swipebox/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css">
</head>

<div id="gallery">
<?php

    include_once('./phpFlickr.php');

    $key = "491566f49be9289";    // enter your API key here
    $secret = "11eb02"; // enter your API secret here
    
    $userid = "163300815@N05"; // Get flickr user id here. Currently points to Jasper Reddin
    
    $f = new phpFlickr($key, $secret);


    $response = $f->people_getPublicPhotos($userid, NULL, "url_m,url_h", 500)['photos']['photo'];

    foreach ($response as $photo) {
        $title = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $photo['title']);

        echo '<a href="' . $photo['url_h'] . '" class="swipebox" title="' . $title . '"><img alt="' . $title . '" src="' . $photo['url_m'] . '"></a>';
    }

?>

</div>

<script>
    $('#gallery').justifiedGallery( {
        rowHeight: 200,
        lastRow: 'nojustify',
        rel: 'Portfolio',
        margins: 2
    });

    $(".swipebox").swipebox({
        loopAtEnd: true
    });
</script>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #gallery {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't link to the PHP library you're using, I'm going to guess that it's [this one by Dan Coulter](https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr), which I note was last updated 7 years ago. However, it allows you to call any method in the Flickr API with [the `->call` method](https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr/blob/bc4f2092b15d347e3d40c19fe0dbff8759fc8e51/phpFlickr.php#L628) so you should be able to use [any of the methods listed on Flickr's documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) to meet your goal.

In particular, there is [a method simply called `flickr.photos.search`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) which allows you to specify a lot of different options for what photos you want. Most relevantly:

- `user_id` to specify whose photos to return
- `bbox` to specify a rectangular / quadrilateral geographical area
- `lat`, `lon`, `radius` and `radius_units` to specify a circular geographical area
- `woe_id` or `place_id` to specify identified places like towns

The documentation says that you can't search for *all* photos in a certain location, and if you don't specify some other limit such as a tag or date, then only photos added in the last 12 hours will be returned.

To find values for `woe_id` and `place_id`, you can use the methods headed "Places", such as [`flickr.places.find`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.places.find.html).

Both methods have wrappers in Dan Coulter's library, so your code might look something like this (completely untested):

```php
$places = $f->places_find('Southampton')['places']['place'];
foreach  ( $places as $place ) {
    echo "<h2>{$place['_content']}</h2>";

    $photos = $f->photos_search([
       'place_id' => $place['place_id'],
       // other search parameters here
       'extras' => 'url_m,url_h',
       'per_page' => 500
    ])['photos']['photo'];

    foreach ( $photos as $photo ) {
         $title = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $photo['title']);
         echo '<a href="' . $photo['url_h'] . '" class="swipebox" title="' . $title . '"><img alt="' . $title . '" src="' . $photo['url_m'] . '"></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your response, I have accepted the answer, however the above code does not output anything, do you know why that could be?

Comment: @JoshBrett Well, I did say it was untested; it's an example of the general approach you might take. Maybe I made a mistake and it's producing some errors, maybe there is no place ID with the name "Southampton", maybe there are no photos uploaded in Southampton in the last 12 hours... You'll need to play around and debug it yourself. If you're not comfortable writing or editing _any_ code, then this is not the right site for you, and you either need to do some tutorials to get that confidence, or consider paying someone to build something for you.